# In Pine Script, display the normalized price of a crypto asset

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to create an indicator that displays the normalized dollar price of bitcoin. I want the price to be equal to 1 on the 1st of May 2023, so that whenever it gets to 2, it means that it has doubled. To do so, my goal is to divide bitcoin price per its 1st of May's price. I don't want to input the price manually because I would like the script to work with other cryptos. The code I thought of is the following:

```
//@version=5

indicator("Normalized BTC", overlay=false)

timeframeInput = input.timeframe("W", "Timeframe")
sourceInput = input.source(hl2, "Source")
periodInput = input(1, "Period")
timestamp_01_05_23 = timestamp(2023, 05, 01)

btcusd_01_05_23 = request.security(input.symbol("BINANCE:BTCUSD", "Symbol"), "D", timestamp_01_05_23)

index = sourceInput / btcusd_01_05_23

plot(index)
```

But unfortunately, the chart displayed is not the one expected. Also, I would like all parts of the calculation to be in function of the input and not directly to BTCUSD. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Normalization will be available only after may 1st, it will be `na` (or whatever you program it to : var float btcusd_01_05_23 = na) before that date

```
//@version=5
indicator("Normalized BTC", overlay=false, precision = 8)

sourceInput = input.source(hl2, "Source")
isym = input.symbol("BINANCE:BTCUSD", "Symbol")

var float btcusd_01_05_23 = na
if  year == 2023  and month == 5 and dayofmonth == 1
    btcusd_01_05_23 := sourceInput

s = request.security(isym, "D", btcusd_01_05_23)

index = sourceInput / s

plot(index)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Isn't there any way to also get the normalized chart before the 1st of May?

Comment: not into future from past